# UISwitch is not working

Tags: ios, uiswitch

First my .h file:

```
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UISwitch *gravaSwitch;
    ...
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UISwitch *gravaSwitch;
...
@end
```

My `viewDidload` in .m file (it works):

```
...
// SET SWITCH BUTTON STATE
keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TrafficApp" accessGroup:nil];

if ( [[keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount] isEqualToString:@"" ] ) 
    [self.gravaSwitch setOn:FALSE];
else [self.gravaSwitch setOn:TRUE];
...
```

But my `switchChanged` doesn't work and I don't know why. On IB everything is right connected, it enters in this method but `gravaSwitch` is always null.

```
- (IBAction)switchChanged:(id)sender
{
    if ( self.gravaSwitch.on )
    {
        NSLog(@"IF");
        [self.gravaSwitch setOn:FALSE animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ELSE");
        [self.gravaSwitch setOn:TRUE animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: You say `gravaSwitch` is always null in your `switchChanged:` method. Have you checked the value of `sender`? If your IBOutlets are hooked up correctly, they should be the same, but if they aren't you could still find a reference to the `UISwitch` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is the following:

```
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UISwitch *gravaSwitch;
    ...
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *gravaSwitch;
...
@end
```

IBOutlet placeholder has to be inserted into @property. Change your code and try to connect your outlet again.

**Edit:**

Try to create your UISwitch programatically. Change your `@property` as the following:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UISwitch *gravaSwitch;
```

Leave `@synthesize` as is. Then in your `viewDidLoad` method add your UISwitch (by default `on` property is FALSE):

```
// Width and height are set to zero but they take the default dimension
UISwitch *yourSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 0, 0)];
// add target and action
mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(yourCustomAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.gravaSwitch = yourSwitch;
// don't forget because gravaSwitch has already a retain policy
[release yourSwitch];

// add the switch to the view
[self.view addSubview:self.gravaSwitch];
```

Within the same controller, but outside the `viewDidLoad` method, add the following method:

```
- (void)yourCustomAction:(id)sender
{
    if ( self.gravaSwitch.on )
    {
        NSLog(@"IF");
        [self.gravaSwitch setOn:FALSE animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ELSE");
        [self.gravaSwitch setOn:TRUE animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  self.gravaSwitch = nil; // remember to dealloc the switch!!
  [super dealloc]
}
```

You could call `self.gravaSwitch = nil;` also in `viewDidUnload` method.

As an alternative you can set gravaSwicth to assign policy as follow. In this case you haven't to call `self.gravaSwitch = nil;` both in `dealloc` and/or `viewDidUnload`.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) UISwitch *gravaSwitch;
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit 2:**

This code works for me. This is the implementation (.m file) for MyViewController.

```
@synthesize gravaSwitch;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwitch *yourSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 0, 0)];
    [yourSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(yourCustomAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    self.gravaSwitch = yourSwitch;

    [yourSwitch release];

    [self.view addSubview:self.gravaSwitch];
}

- (void)yourCustomAction:(id)sender
{
    if(self.gravaSwitch.on)
    {
        NSLog(@"on");
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@"off");
    }
}
```

where gravaSwicth is declared within MyViewController.h as follows:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
     UISwitch *gravaSwitch;
     ...
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UISwitch *gravaSwitch;
...
@end
```

rembember to call `self.gravaSwicth = nil` in dealloc in MyViewController.m!!

Comment: It didn't work! :(
I've uploaded two images which shows how I hooked it up.
http://imageshack.us/g/205/screenshot20111215at115.png/

Comment: sorry, do you have synthesized the property? In your implementation class put `@synthesize graveSwicth`. If not, it couldn't work :)

Comment: Yes, I did! :( In the begging of @implementation

Comment: Weird, when I put that code, the IB's switch works, but the code one has the same behavior that the IB one had. If I comment the `addSubview:self.gravaSwitch` then my program crashes when I press the switch.

Comment: @Vellozo You have to remove the UISwitch created with IB. Leave only the UISwitch created programatically. `addSubview:self.gravaSwitch` is manadatory to see your switch in the screen if you create the swicth by code. So, to summarize: cancel the switch created in IB and use the code I provided above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I did... but it isn't working. If I cancel the switch created in IB, as I said, my program crashes.
Anyway... thanks.

Comment: With only code's UISwitch, 'self.gravaSwitch = nil' and the program always enters on ELSE in 'switchChanged:' method, as the code that I've posted in the beginning. :(

Comment: I provided some code in Edit 2. The code works for me...I don't where it could be the problem!!!

Comment: upvote or mark the answer as correct if you want :-) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I had this problem when my UISwitch was in a UITableViewCell, and I put it at the top of the list of subviews in Interface Builder (and therefore beneath the other views in the cell when running). It worked in a develop build but not a production build for who knows what reason. In prod, I would click on the UISwitch and the whole row would blink ask if selected.

So I moved it to the bottom of the list (and therefore above the other views in the cell when running) and then I could click on the UISwitch.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)alarmSwitchToggled:(id)sender
{


    if ([switchAlarm isOn]) {
        NSLog(@"switch is ON");
    }
    else
    {
                   NSLog(@"switch is OFF");


    }
    }
```

Give proper connections in nib file and dont forget to make it as `valuechanged` instead of `touchupinside`