# How to call an action when UISwitch changes state?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiswitch

I want to perform some action when UISwitch changes its state, thus is set on or off. How do I do this? I need to pass two objects as parameters.

It's created in code, thus not using xib.

Comment: Refer this link [UISwitch action](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521373/1072867)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
[yourSwitchObject addTarget:self action:@selector(setState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

This will call the below method when your switch state changes

```
- (void)setState:(id)sender 
{
    BOOL state = [sender isOn];
    NSString *rez = state == YES ? @"YES" : @"NO";
    NSLog(rez);
}
```

Comment: How would you set the delegate? I don't see a `delegate` property or a `- setDelegate` function.

Comment: No need to set delegate, Its your own method dude ;)

Answer (score 16):

Obviously we can do the same with Swift, here is the code (compiled and worked with the latest version of the **Swift 3.1**)

Add action to your switch button:

```
mySwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
```

And implement this method:

```
@objc func switchValueDidChange(sender:UISwitch!) {
    print(sender.isOn)
}
```

Or even if you are not using the sender you may remove:

```
func switchValueDidChange() {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution for me (worked with swift 4):

```
@IBAction func toggleSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if(mySwitch.isOn) {
        //Do something
    } else {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Link the above function with value changed in Sent Events under connection tab