# Xcode 6 - How to hide textfield in one viewcontroller from af switch in another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller (firstViewController) with a switch button. The switch button should show / hide a text field in the secondViewController. How can I do it?

Comment: How is showed the second view controller?

Comment: Have you tried anything by now?

Comment: Yes but can't get this to work...... I can't figure out how to make the delegate between my first and secondViewController

Answer (score 1):

Your app should be structured according to the [*Model-View-Controller*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) design pattern. You need to do this:

- Add a `BOOL hideText` variable to your model class
- Set `model.hideText` to the value of the switch in the switch [event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8589775/335858)
- Check `model.hideText` in the `viewWillAppear` handler of the view that has the text field
- If `model.hideText` is set, hide the text field; otherwise, show it

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple it is.You just have to use `delegate` design pattern.Go through this link [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

In your code you have to do something like this. I suppose your switch is in secondViewCOntroller and you have to make textField hide on SwitchON in FirstViewController

Step 1) Create Protocol in second View controller like this and create property of that delegate.Pass the value of your switch in switchButtonPressed Method and call that delegate method there.

```
@protocol secondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)switchButtonPressedOn:(BOOL)switchOn;

@end

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *switchOutlet;
@property(weak,nonatomic)id<secondViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
- (IBAction)switchButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

In switchButtonPressed,

```
- (IBAction)switchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
if(self.switchOutlet.on==YES)

[self.delegate switchButtonPressedOn:YES];
```

}

Step 2) 
In FirstViewController,

```
  #import "swiftViewController.h"

@interface ViewController :   UIViewController<secondViewControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property BOOL mySwitchState;

@end
```

Step 3) set `delegate=self` in `prepareForSegue` method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    secondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
destViewController.delegate = self;
}
-(void)switchButtonPressedOn:(BOOL)switchOn{
NSLog(@"Method Called");

if (switchOn==YES) {
self.textField.hidden=YES;
}else{
    self.textField.hidden=NO;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to hide textField in nextViewController then pass the switchState to nextViewController in `prepareForSegueMethod`,

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
thirdViewController *thirdVC=segue.destinationViewController;
if (self.switchOutlet.on==YES) {
thirdVC.isSomethingEnabled=YES;    
         }

   }
```

and in nextViewController, in `viewDidLoad`, hide your textField.

```
    if (self.isSomethingEnabled==YES) {
    self.textField.hidden=YES;
}
```

Working perfectly. This is very important concept in iOS. Go through the above link.

Comment: Thanks Saheb :-)I have the Switch in firstViewController and want the text field in secondViewController to hide :-)

Comment: Its more simpler than previous.I updated my answer. If it is helpful then vote it right, :-)